# wget() not accepting anything past the first argument

Tags: curl, cron, wget

I'm trying to invoke a wget via crontab to run a script from my domain. However, it seems that wget isn't accepting anything past the first argument (in this case `action=all`).

How can I get wget to either accept this past the first argument OR how can I rewrite this as a `curl` command instead.

```
 wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0" -q -O - "$@" http://www.example.com/potd_generator.php?action=all&cron=yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because of the `&` sign in the URL. In shells like `bash` it means "go to the background".

Wrap the URL into quotes.